# AngularJS web app with Express and Node.js server and a MongoDB local database

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I have done much research on this question due to me learning through trial and error with the MEAN stack. When accessing the mongoimported json file in which has the object's data is saved in it. How do I use the Express GET method to retrieve the object from the local MongoDB database to communicate to the Angular factory and display the object's data? The URL parameters are based on the Angular UI-Router's state settings saved within the config file of the controller.

### routes/contests.js

```
    (function() {
  "use strict";

  var express = require("express");
  var router = express.Router();
  var mongoose = require("mongoose");
  var Contest = mongoose.model("Contest");

  router.route("/contests")
    .get(function(req, res, next) {
      Contest.find(function(err, contests) {
        if(err) {
          return next(err);
        }

        Contest.populate(contests, {
          path: "matchups",
          select: "nbaTeams"
        }).then(function(contests) {
          res.json(contests);
        });
      });
    });

router.route("/contests/:contest")
  .get(function(req, res, next) {
    Contest.populate(req.contest, {
      path: "matchups",
    }).then(function(contest) {
      Matchups.populate(req.contest.matchups, {
        path: "nbaTeams",
        select: "team"
      }).then(function(matchups) {
        res.json(contest);
      });
    });
  });

router.param("contest", function(req, res, next, id) {
  var query = Contest.findById(id);

  query.exec(function(err, contest) {
    if(err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if(!contest) {
      return next(new Error("cannot find the contest"));
    }
    req.contest = contest;
    return next();
  });
});

  module.exports = router;
})();
```

### controllers/contestController.js

```
(function()
{
  "use strict";

  var app = angular.module("sportsApp.controllers.contest", ["ui.router"]);

  app.config(["$stateProvider", function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("contest", {
      parent: "root",
      url: "/contests/{id}",
      views: {
        "container@": {
          templateUrl: "partials/contests",
          controller: "ContestController"
        }
      },
      resolve: {
        contest: [
          "$stateParams", "contestService", function($stateParams, contestService) {
            return contestService.get($stateParams.id);
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  }
]);

app.controller("ContestController", ["$scope","contestService", "contest", function($scope, contestService, contest) {
  $scope.contest = contest;
}]);
})();
```

### services/contestService.js

```
   (function() {
  "use strict";

  var app = angular.module("sportsApp.services.contest", []);

  app.factory("contestService", ["$http",
  function($http)
  {
    var o = {
      contests: []
    };

    function getAll() {
      return $http.get("/contests").then(function(res) {
        angular.copy(res.data, o.contests);
      });
    }

    function get(id) {
      return $http.get("/contests/" + id).then(function(res) {
        return res.data;
      });
    }

    o.getAll = getAll;
    o.get = get;

    return o;
  }]);
})();
```

### app.js

```
    var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var ngResource = require("ng-resource");

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("./models/Users");
require("./models/Nbateam");
require("./models/Contest");
require("./models/Matchup");


var passport = require("passport");
require("./config/passport");

var indexRoutes = require("./routes/index");
var partialsRoutes = require("./routes/partials");
var authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");
var usersRoutes = require("./routes/users");
var nbaTeamsRoutes = require("./routes/nbateams");
var contestRoutes = require("./routes/contests");

var app = express();

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/sportsapp");

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use("/", indexRoutes);
app.use("/", partialsRoutes);
app.use("/", authRoutes);
app.use("/", usersRoutes);
app.use("/", nbaTeamsRoutes);
app.use("/", contestRoutes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

### JSON file I mongoimported

```
    [{
    "_id": 1,
    "matchups": [{
        "matchupId": 1,
        "selectedTeam": "",
        "matchupWinner": "Atlanta",
        "nbaTeams": [{
            "team": "Portland",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/Portland-Trail-Blazers-Logo.png"
        }, {
            "team": "Atlanta",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/atl-hawks.png"
        }]
    }, {
        "matchupId": 2,
        "selectedTeam": "",
        "matchupWinner": "Dallas",
        "nbaTeams": [{
            "team": "Dallas",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/Dallas-Mavericks.png"
        }, {
            "team": "Detroit",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/DET.png"
        }]
    }, {
        "matchupId": 3,
        "selectedTeam": "",
        "matchupWinner": "Golden State",
        "nbaTeams": [{
            "team": "Golden State",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/GSW.png"
        }, {
            "team": "Memphis",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/Memphis-Grizzlies.png"
        }]
    }, {
        "matchupId": 4,
        "selectedTeam": "",
        "matchupWinner": "Oklahoma City",
        "nbaTeams": [{
            "team": "Oklahoma City",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/OKC-Thunder.png"
        }, {
            "team": "Pheonix",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/Pheonix-Suns.jpg"
        }]
    }, {
        "matchupId": 5,
        "selectedTeam": "",
        "matchupWinner": "Utah",
        "nbaTeams": [{
            "team": "Sacremento",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/Sacremento-Kings.jpg"
        }, {
            "team": "Utah",
            "logo": "stylesheets/nbalogos/Utah-Jazz.jpg"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I am trying to display this list of information on the individual contest page per an _id query. Before I made changes to the code I was getting a 500: Internal server error because the ./contests/1 parameter does not exist. Now the link is dead and gives no errors.

Comment: Not sure that you're using Mongoose#populate correctly. I believe you need to do a query first before you run populate (which is used to essentially populate references in the one mongo object with another mongo object to create larger data structures).

Also, for those route parameters to work in Express, you need to use `req.params.contest`, etc., not just `req.contest`. That is how you access route parameters (and this is pretty consistent among the other Node server frameworks).

Comment: You would want something more like `Model.find(req.params.id).populate().exec(callback)`, but looking at your data it doesn't even look like there are references to populate.

Comment: It's a nested mongoose model array that the contest object references the Matchup model which references the Nbateam model. So using the populate method wouldn't work for this format of the JSON file I mongoimported?

Comment: Well, the way `.populate()` works is that there is a value in one of your fields that references the `_id` of a different model's object and replaces it. So matchups would be an array of `_id`s that represent the unique ids for each matchup. `.populate()` would go into mongo, find these matchup objects, and place them in the array for you. The way your data is now, you just have one big contest object that is already populated.

Each model should essentially correspond to a collection in mongo. If you look in mongo and you only have one collection, thats a sign you just have a nested object.

Comment: So how would I go about displaying the matchup's information on the contest page? I only get an empty table and even when I input {{contest._id}} nothing is displayed but the empty table.

Comment: You should be using `.find()` instead of `.populate()`. Since you have no actual references, populate won't do anything. You need to do something like `Contest.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, contest){})

Comment: This will return a single contest object based on the `_id`, rather than an array. You do not need to populate it because you are not storing references, you have all of the data already in the Contest object that you imported. That said, if your mongoose model does not match what you are pulling from Mongo, you may get an error.

Comment: Ok thanks for the input P Ackerman!